# Why no simanim for Rus, Shir HaShirim, and Eicha?

Tags: tanach, book-of-ruth, shir-hashirim, lamentations-eicha, ketuvim

In the Koren Tanakh, besides for the church-invented chapter system, it also puts the Jewish simanim divisions at the side of the page. Why does it not do this for Rus, Shir HaShirim, and Eicha?

Comment: How do know it doesn't? Maybe they are one chapter long?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. However would you mind posting pictures or providing a link for visual purposes?